# How to insert a checkbox value into a database table if it's checked?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have these two check boxes on my HTML form.

```
<div class="label-input-wrapper pickup">    
        <div class="form-label">I need Airport pick-up</div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="checkbox" name="pick_up_yes" value="yes" />Yes 
            <input type="checkbox" name="pick_up_no" value="no" />No
            <div class="error-msg">
                <?php if(isset($errors['pick_up_no'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['pick_up_no'].'</span>'; } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Upon the form submission values are saved like this:

```
$pick_up_yes = $_POST["pick_up_yes"];
$pick_up_no = $_POST["pick_up_no"];
```

and the validation:

```
if (($pick_up_yes != yes) && ($pick_up_no != no)){
            //Blank string, add error to $errors array.        
            $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Please let us know your airport pick up requirement!";
        }
```

I want to save this `Yes` or `No` into my data base when the form is submitted.
My database column name for that `air_port_pick_up`.
How can I save this into the database? If the `pick_up_yes` check box is selected then I want to save the `Yes` into `air_port_pick_up`
If the `pick_up_no` check box is selected then I want to save the `No` into `air_port_pick_up`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must give same name attr for both input (name="pickup")

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="yes" />Yes</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="no" />No</p>
```

Add checked attr like below

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="yes" checked />Yes</p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="no" />No</p>
```

to skip this step

```
   if (($pick_up_yes != yes) && ($pick_up_no != no)){
        //Blank string, add error to $errors array.        
        $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Please let us know your airport pick up requirement!";
    }
```

Now you can store value:

```
$value = $_POST['pickup'];
```

Comment: but `$value = $_POST['pickup'];` gives Yes and no on the mail where I get form details filled by the customer... but I want to know which one is selected

Comment: By default it is automatically selected "YES". And if you get value as "NO" then they have clicked "NO".

Answer (score 2):

Give same name to checkboxes :-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="yes" />Yes 
<input type="checkbox" name="pick_up" value="no" />No
```

Then, in post value `$_POST["pick_up"]`, you will only get that value which you have selected.

Comment: if I use this I am getting bot Yes and No values

Comment: have you selected both ?

Comment: sorry that works fine.. I forgot to update the assigned variable to `$_POST["pick_up"]`